# masm assembly,when linking obj files i am getting errors: unresolved externals

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

i am going through assembly programming for earlier ms dos source code. i am trying to link three obj files, but it is giving me error as:

```
**unresolved external:**

BADLD_POST in file(s):
       SYSINIT.OBJ(BIOS)
RE_INIT in file(s):
       SYSINIT.OBJ(BIOS)
BADCOUNTRY in file(s)
       SYSINIT.OBJ(BIOS)
```

---

```
in SYSINIT.ASM file these variables are as follows:
EXTERN BADLD_POST:BYTE
EXTERN RE_INIT:BYTE
EXTERN BADCOUNTRY:BYTE
  ............
  ............
MOV BX,OFFSET BADLD_POST
  ............
  ............
END
```

i have expand a lot of time in this. please help.
thanks in advance.
one more trouble here:
may you help me in understanding the concepts of
(1)entry_point of a program
(2)invoke

Comment: You need to include an object file with a definition of the symbols, not just an `extern` reference to them.  The C equivalent would be linking a bunch of files with `extern int foo;`, but no file with `int foo = 1;`.  Or with prototypes but not definitions for functions.

Comment: Sorry to say it again, but this is not going to be easy. I once worked for a company having a DOS 2 source license, and vaguely remember that it took a group of guys perhaps 6 months to prepare a complete DOS distribution. And they had access to MS' internal tech support to help them out with the details. The DOS kit *was* delivered as source code because it wasn't complete and you had to add a non-trivial amount of code to adapt it to your specific hardware. Perhaps those adaptions are the parts you are missing?